# Scatter Animation python

Tags: python, plot

I have my data file containing x,y coordinates of a fractal. I want to get a animation of this coordinates.

I have tried this code.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

data1=np.loadtxt('data.txt')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
scat = ax.scatter([], [])

def init():
        scat.set_offsets([])
    return scat

def animate(i):
    scat.set_offsets(data1)
    return scat

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=700, interval=1, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Error is 'PathCollection' object is not iterable.
I don't know much, any help will be thankful.

Comment: `plt` is `matplotlib` right?, please put up your entire code.

Comment: @MrakVladar done

Comment: error : 'PathCollection' object is not iterable. with a blank plot.

Comment: @SourabhMittal post few lines of you data.txt

Comment: data file contain data of barnsley fern

Comment: @SourabhMittal you need to animate creation of points from data or movement of this points in some direction?

Comment: When I type `scat.set_offsets([])` in the REPL  I get a backtrace with error `ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2` — I have to think that what you showed us is different from your actual code.